# Token Type not allowed when using simple-slack-api to connect with "xoxb-...." bot token to Slack

Tags: java, api, bots, slack

I'm using https://github.com/Itiviti/simple-slack-api and try to connect to Slack with the token starting with xoxb- (called Bot User Auth Access Token)

```java
var session = SlackSessionFactory.createWebSocketSlackSession("xoxb-....");
session.connect();
```

Connect gets a "not_allowed_token_type" response which then results in the Exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: not_allowed_token_type
    at com.ullink.slack.simpleslackapi.impl.SlackWebSocketSessionImpl.connectImpl(SlackWebSocketSessionImpl.java:338) ~[simple-slack-api-1.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.ullink.slack.simpleslackapi.impl.SlackWebSocketSessionImpl.connect(SlackWebSocketSessionImpl.java:292) ~[simple-slack-api-1.2.0.jar:na]
```

The configured bot scopes are chat:write, reactions:read and reactions:write.

The Bot/App is installed in a Workspace.

How to connect to Slack and what token to use?

Comment: Maybe the API implementation is old and doesn't support the new Bot API with granular permissions.

Comment: Yeah it's from 2017... You won't get far with that library.

Comment: Make sure that your slack bot authentication token is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The API implementation you are referring has been updated and doesn't support the new Bot API with granular permissions. Refer to the [github-issue](https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/921) for details.

However if you want to send messages directly to your slack channel via bot you can use `Webhook URL` configured for your Workspace. But before you try that, Make sure that your bot is added to the channel already and webhook URL is configured properly. Refer to [incoming-webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) for details.

Refer to the below code which sends a greet message ***Hello, World!*** to the slack channel when invoked.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Slack {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppController.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   
        try {
            String webhook_url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/B0XXXXUXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            HttpHeaders httpheaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpheaders.set("Content-Type","application/json");
            httpheaders.add("Accept", "application/json");

            JSONObject payload = new JSONObject(); 
            payload.put("text","Hello, World!");

            HttpEntity<String> httppentity = new HttpEntity<String>(payload.toString(),httpheaders);

            String response = restTemplate.exchange(webhook_url, HttpMethod.POST,httppentity,String.class).getBody();
            
            logger.info(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You will see a greet message in your channel, something like :

[image: Bot Message]